# How can we trigger Jenkins build when jira project version is released?

Tags: jenkins, jira, webhooks, jenkins-generic-webhook-trigger

I want to trigger a Jenkins build when jira project version is released. For this i tried generic-webhook-trigger but i don't know why its not working. I am new on this platform and don't know from where i can check the issue.
my jira webhook URL is
[http://127.0.0.1:8085/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=${project.key}${version.id}](http://127.0.0.1:8085/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=$%7Bproject.key%7D$%7Bversion.id%7D)

Comment: Moreover if i hit this url directly on browser i got this error.  {"jobs":null,"message":"Did not find any jobs with GenericTrigger configured! If you are using a token, you need to pass it like ...trigger/invoke?token=TOKENHERE. If you are not using a token, you need to authenticate like http://user:passsword@jenkins/generic-webhook... "}